# X Files known by other name?

Tags: the-x-files

I was just searching on IMDB for movies with the word "Dark" in the title ([results](http://www.imdb.com/find?q=dark&s=tt&ref_=fn_al_tt_mr)), and I noticed a ways down that the X-Files tv series had an annotation under it that lists another name:

> aka "Files in the Dark"

I tried to search for it on google, and I can't find anything related to the X-Files, nor is it listed on the Wikipedia page about the series.  Can someone provide me with some source for where this comes from?

Comment: Trivia:  Original title in France used to be "Aux Frontières Du Réel", something like "The Reality Limits", as a reference to "Au-Delà Du Réel", title used in France for the series "The Outer Limits".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Er, the answer is right on The X Files [IMDb aka page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106179/releaseinfo#akas):

> Israel (Hebrew title) (literal English title)  Files in the Dark

And they pronounce it Tikim b'Afela ([source](http://www.internationalhero.co.uk/h/hebrewc.htm)).

Comment: Just as a note, the Hebrew word translated here as "Dark" points to more than dark (which, literally would just be "khoshekh") -- it is more "darkness, pitch blackness ; despair, despondency ; dark (noun), unknown"